# Implication of an invalid interval on a statement

Tags: combinatorics

Apologies for the basic question, I certainly feel like I should know the answer to this. I'm trying to understand the paper On the structure of sum-free sets 2, 1999 (if it matters)

The paper has the following proposition (among many other things):
[image]

We have that $m,M \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $m\leq M$. In fact, given a set we know the values of $m$ and $M$ - I'm trying to figure out $C$.

Does 4.1 imply that $M/5-C \geq C$ (leading to a valid interval),
or,
does it imply that if $M/5-C<C$, then the statement is true for any value of $m$?

many thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd like to reassure you that this proposition is stated in a very confusing way.

Comment: IMO, it must be intended that M must be "large enough" in order that $\frac M 5 - C$ is larger than C. Thus, we have that the interval $[C, \frac M 5 - C]$ is not empty. Obviously, for an $m$ whatever, it is enough to choose $C > m$ and - with the above proviso - $m$ will not belong to the interval.

Comment: Having said that, if the choice of $M$ is not "suitable" and the interval is empty, then of course $m \notin [C, \ldots]$ for $C$ whatever.

Comment: Without some context on what $m$ and $M$ and these "general assumptions" are, it is impossible to tell. You could read ahead to see what the proof does, to see if $C < \frac M{10}$ is justifiable by it. Or to see what conclusions the author makes by this proposition, to figure out what the intent was.